# train Cascade ObjectDetector matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, object-detection, training-data, matlab-cvst

I'm asking about how can'i use the trainCascadeObjectDetector while i already create a positive smples structre composed of filename and bonding boxes cordinates. Also i hase a negative exemple images file. But when i lnche the function as flow

```
trainCascadeObjectDetector('newDetector.xml', str, negativeFolder, 'FalseAlarmRate', 0.2, 'NumCascadeStages', 5);
```

I have this error:

```
Error using trainCascadeObjectDetector>parseInputs (line 306)
Argument 'POSITIVE_INSTANCES' failed validation with error:
Cannot find struct field 'imageFilename' in POSITIVE_INSTANCES.

Error in trainCascadeObjectDetector (line 161)
parser = parseInputs(varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error itself says, the str does not contain a field called `imageFilename`, which should be the field where the image files are. Quoting matlab documentation:

> POSITIVE_INSTANCES is an array of structs with information  about the
>   positive instances.  The struct fields are:
>       imageFilename          - A string that specifies the image 
>                                name. The image can be true color, 
>                                grayscale, or indexed, in any of the 
>                                formats supported by IMREAD.
>
> ```
> objectBoundingBoxes    - An M-by-4 matrix of [x y width height] 
>                          bounding boxes specifying object
>                          locations.
> ```

So, your `str` argument should be a array of structs with this information, i.e (file1 has 3 boxes, file2 2 and file3 4):

```
str = struct('imageFileName',{'file1Path', 'file2Path', 'file3Path'},...
  'objectBoundingBoxes',{[xBox1 yBox1 w1 h1;xBox2 yBox2 w2 h2;xBox3 yBox3 w3 h3]...
  [xBox1 yBox1 w1 h1;xBox2 yBox2 w2 h2],... 
  [xBox1 yBox1 w1 h1;xBox2 yBox2 w2 h2;xBox3 yBox3 w3 h3,xBox4 yBox4 w4 h4]});
```

Or any other way you want to declare it. But be sure that you input files in this format.

Comment: off-topic but you seem to have experience in cascaded classifiers in MatLab. I need to know approximately how long would it take to train a cascaded classifier (using gentleboost) on 600 positive and 300 negative images? given 16GB RAM. Even a vague approximate would help tremendously!

Comment: @user961627 sorry, can't help you with that, I don't use this stuff. I just helped the OP as the error was just the syntax.